# upload file to server after choosing the file from dialog

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following input:

and the following javascript:

```
function click(){

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var bufferFile;

    var fileName = $('#upload').val();

    reader.onload = function (event) {

        bufferFile = event.target.result;

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('fname', fileName);
        fd.append('bufferFile', bufferFile);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            };
        });

    };
}
```

what I actually want is to upload the selected file into a file upload in the server.

The `upload.php` contains the upload function. When selecting a file, actually nothing happens what is going wrong?

Comment: Look this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery][1] - may be it will be useful for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery